# Once an application is available in the App Store, is it possible to change the developer/seller account?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

We are developing an app for a client who is currently in the process of creating their own Apple account.

The problem is they got started with the process late, and we need to submit the app ASAP for review.

Has anyone had any experience with changing the seller account after an app has been approved and is available in the App Store?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 3):

According to most reports, the only way to do this is to remove the app from the old account, and submit it under the new account as a new and different app.  Ratings, reviews, saved settings/etc. and update-ability will not transfer, since they are tied to the app ID, and the app ID has to be a new and unique in the destination account.

Answer (score 3):

Yes is possible, but you must contact people at Apple and start a quite long and procedure with papers and stuffs. Best way to start is to ask a "general app/appstore question" in the "contact us" section of iTunesConnect site.